# React Native - Delay between changing bottom tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, cross-platform

I have used react navigation's "createBottomTabNavigator" in one of my projects.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


</Tab.Navigator>
................
    <Tab.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
        {configuration.paymentProviders.length > 0 && (
          <Tab.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
    )}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

My problem is this:

If I switch between two tabs quickly, after a while, the render cannot work properly because it tries to perform the operation without getting a response from the API.

For this, I added setLoading(true) to the API request and did not set it to false until the request was finished, but I still have the same problem, although it is better.

So, I want to give a half-second pause between tabs, do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you switch the tabs, you use somthing like `onClick()` right? [Here is old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987789/how-do-i-add-a-delay-on-a-button-click-in-react) for the solution as `setTimeout`. It gives you the ability to delay before the code gets executed. But I advice you do disable all other buttons, before you get a response. This also means that you need to be sure that response will come, at least `timeout`, then you can enable buttons again.

A better option might be to consider not delaying the process but just simply disabling all buttons which have `onClick` functionality, to prevent too many requests. This is an example of disabling something, doesn't neccessarely needs to be a button.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);

  //fake request, just delaying things
  function handleClick() {
    setClicked(true); // disable all buttons if clicked
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClicked(false);
    }, 2000);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clicked);
  }, [clicked]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={!clicked ? handleClick : undefined}>1</button>
      <button onClick={!clicked ? handleClick : undefined}>2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```